# Why can't Android Manifast find my Activities? (when using Build Variants with Application Suffixes)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-manifest

thank you for reading and any advice given. I am still very new to Android (less than a year) and have so far only worked with one build type/variant (main) while building an app and am now in the process of trying to create 3 different build variants in anticipation of a test release. (Very much like found on this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types) So I'm trying to work through separating this out now.

My variants shall be .debug, .release. and .staging . I am not trying to use productFlavors, as I don't really have separate versions of my app, just those 3 different build variants. I am not sure if I HAVE TO use product Flavors but to me (so far) it appeared that it doesn't really apply to my app. (Please advise if that's incorrect)

My app also uses google-services/Firebase but that part seems to be working for me. (separate google json file for each build variant)

Here is an excerpt from my gradle: (I used a generic package name that corresponds to what I have)

```
android {
    {...}
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.app"
        {...}
    }
    
    signingConfigs {
        {...}
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            applicationIdSuffix ".release"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          {...}
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
            {...}
        }
        staging {
            initWith debug
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.staging
        }

    }
    sourceSets {        
        debug {
            setRoot 'src/debug'
            manifest.srcFile 'src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        staging {
            setRoot 'src/staging'
            manifest.srcFile 'src/staging/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        release {
            setRoot 'src/release'
            manifest.srcFile 'src/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
    {...}
}
```

Here is my Manifest Header:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.android.app.staging">
```

So first, because I now specify my build variants and application suffixes in my gradle it throws following error: (but maybe this is where something is already not right)

> Manifest merger failed : Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-60 value=(com.example.android.app.staging)
> has a different value=(com.example.android.app.staging) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-52
> Suggestion: remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml   and place it in the build.gradle:
> flavorName {
> applicationId = "com.example.android.app.staging"
> }

But when I remove `package="com.example.android.app.staging"` all my activities can no longer be found, because I suppose they were getting their reference from the package attribute. (Upon removing the package attribute all the activities turn red, ergo could not be found. (`android:name=".MainActivity"`).

I want to add, that I still have my "main" srcSet in place including a Manifest, if that information is relevant. I suppose once I have all this separated, I will (can I?) get rid of it/empty it out.

So what do I need to do to keep references in tact in each of my Manifests for each build variant?

I suppose I could change all those activity names in each Manifest to something like: `android:name="com.example.android.app.staging.MainActivity"` (or .release/.debug) But I would think that the build tools do that automatically -- or is this what I have to do?

My goal is simply to have 3 build variants (.debug, .staging and .release). Not having much experience with app releases I am not 100% confident this is the right approach, but seems to make sense for my use.

Thank you for your time and advice. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out I had my folder path/folder structure wrong; and nobody here would've known that because I didn't even post that as I just assumed it was correct. (ugh, should have known better)

Because of the applicationId suffix at the end, I automatically assumed that my package must add a folder/path at the end, like so:

`/src/release/java/com/example/android/app/release`

After some back and forth I finally looked at this path and just found it odd, that I would have a "release root folder" suffixed with release in the end. I just removed that last folder/path and tried it that way. E voila. Full on idiot here. xD

So my path - obviously - needed to be this:

`/src/release/java/com/example/android/app`

Then my package names in my Android Manifests also won't require that odd suffixed package name no longer.(which lead to some other issues in my code, as well)

I doubt very many people will run into this same stupid mistake, but just in case, I'll leave this topic up and answer it, instead of deleting my shame. Haha.